# Отличие способов хранения результирующих данных в T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Какие основные отличия этих сущностей?

- временная таблица
- обобщенное табличное выражение
- курсор

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Временные таблицы бывают двух видов. Таблицы переменные(@Table), временные таблицы(#table), ещё есть таблицы вида ##table, отличаются от #table областью видимости.

В связи с этим, можно дать краткое описание:

- Таблицы переменные - хранятся в оперативной памяти(если её хватает). Доступна в блоке кода, т.е. её можно переиспользовать в разных запросах. имеет локальную область видимости, так же как любая другая локальная переменная.
- Временные таблицы. Хранятся в tempdb, имеют более широкую область видимости, а именно по всему стеку вызовов. Т.е. если процедура А создала таблицу #A, потом вызвала процедуру B, которая создала таблицу #B - то и А имеет доступ к #B(после вызова В) и В имеет доступ к #A. Так же на временные таблицы можно создавать индексы, триггеры и прочее, в отличии от таблиц переменных.
  Таблицы ##Table имеют глобальную область видимости. Если кто-то создал таблицу ##Table - её видят все сессии, а существует она до тех пор, пока "жива" хоть одна сессия, которая обращалась к этой таблице.
- СТЕ. Тут область вилимости только внутри **одного** запроса! Т.е. переиспользовать результат нельзя. Более того, если вы обращаетесь к СТЕ несколько раз внутри одного апроса - она будет **вычислена столько же раз**! Есть недокументированные способы заставить оптимизатор запомнить СТЕ в оперативной памяти для повторного использования, но это совсем другая история:)
- Курсоры. В общем это немного из другой оперы... Курсоры позволяют построчно обрабатывать данные и предназначены не для хранения. Внутри курсора можно вызывать выполнение процедур, чего нельзя делать в запросе.

Добавлю ещё своё субъективное мнение когда что нужно использовать.

- Таблицы переменные. Когда нужно использовать небольшое количество данных. Например промежуточный результат сложного запроса записать в таблицу переменную, разбив тем самым сложный запрос на два простых.
- Временные таблицы. Когда информации довольно много и/или её нужно передать в другое место выполнения. Эти таблицы ничем не отличаются от обычных таблиц, кроме того, что не нужно беспокоиться о их очищении и удалении.
- СТЕ - когда нельзя использовать временные таблицы(т.е. такие места, которые обязывают нас использовать только один SQL запрос), Например, внутри тела табличной функции.
- Курсоры - когда нельзя обойтись другими способами. Например, когда для каждой строки временного результата нужно запустить выполнение хранимой процедуры. В MS SQL курсоры обычно работают медленнее запросов. Так что елси есть возможность - лучше их избегать.

Comment: пункт 4 *Например, внутри тела табличной функции.* можно более подробно и еще если есть плюсы и минусы, как например CTE более оперативно работает по сравнению с временными таблицами#